# How Play to audio list in os.startfile use Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, audio-player, python-vlc

How Play to audio list in os.startfile use Python?

### MY CODE:

```
import os

music_dir = "C:\\Users\\JACKSON KASI\\Music"
songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
print(songs)

for i in songs:
    os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir,i))
```

The next audio file should run after the first audio file is fully functional.
But my code is play all audio fast. It's not perfectly.
***someone help me please.***

Do you can use **pygame** (OR) **python-vlc** use to solve this proplem.

Answer (score 0):

`os.startfile` is just launching the file asynchronously in the background. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile):

> `startfile()` returns as soon as the associated application is launched. There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to retrieve the application’s exit status.

Basically, you can't use it for your purpose, because there's no way to know when it's done.

There are many, many walkthroughs for playing media files; please search the web for solutions (providing a complete solution from scratch is somewhat beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question).

Answer (score 0):

```
random = os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir , songs[1])
```

this will work

Comment: Welcome to SO! @aryanjadhav, how does this address the question, where multiple audio files need to be played?